# TransactionTooLargeException when appying wallpaper

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I know that `TransactionTooLargeException` occurs when there is a large amount of data being transferred between services in the system. Usually, I would have some kind of control if I were to transfer large amount of data, but in this case, when I'm appying a wallpaper, I don't have that amount of control.

I'm applying a wallpaper by first cropping it with `android-image-cropper`, and then applying it by

```
WallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

...in a **separate thread**, to avoid overloading the UI thread. Now, when I press "apply wallpaper", and wait for some time, and then return to the homescreen, it works flawlessly, but when I apply the wallpaper and then immediately return to the homescreen, I get the alert that the app has crashed, along with this log:

```
07-31 18:50:41.611 32720-32720/elementary.elementarywallpapers E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 16385936)
07-31 18:50:41.614 32720-32720/elementary.elementarywallpapers D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-31 18:50:41.621 32720-32720/elementary.elementarywallpapers E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: elementary.elementarywallpapers, PID: 32720
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 16385936 bytes
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3752)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 16385936 bytes
                                                                                     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3606)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3744)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

How can I fix this?